# Splunk query to extract a number (time taken)

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk query result such as below:

`2020-04-09 23:33:51.120  INFO 1 --- [an-885-exec-8] c.z.q.p.serv.backendCall      : time taken 11793 in ms`

I want to extract the number after string "time taken" and table the result

I tried the below query

`index=my-platform ": time taken" | rex ".*:\stime\taken\s(?P<time_taken>(\d+))\sin\sms" | table time_taken`

This query results in a blank table and prints nothing.

Can anyone help with the right query to extract just the number next to time taken?

Comment: I think you are missing a `s` before the `taken` part. `\stime\staken\s`.

Comment: oh yeah thanks it worked

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `field=<field_name>` in the `rex`:

```
| rex field=_raw "taken\s(?<time_taken>\d+)\s"
```

Will do it - https://regex101.com/r/gYuN7w/1/