# Splunk query to check if time taken of specific log is greater than N ms?

Tags: regex, regex-group, splunk

For Splunk I was trying something like below along with what has been provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450330/splunk-query-to-extract-a-number-time-taken)
But it's mostly related to extracting digits, what I'm looking for is to check value is greater than some xyz number.
It will be great if someone can help me with it.

I'm not much good at regex, so tried a couple of stuff like as given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640192/regular-expressions-matching-if-number-is-greater-then) as well. But it's not working.

Splunk query:
`index=1234 application_instance_name=service-name "[FooBarService#write] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (2300ms)"`
I know the above is for exactly matching, but I played with regex as given in both the links.

log: `[FooBarService#write] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (2300ms)`

In this case, how should I check how many logs for this match have crossed 5000ms?
What query shall I build in spunk search for the same?

Comment: Please focus this posting on a single question and ask the other question in a separate post.  Please also share the regular expressions you've tried and how they've not met expectations.

Comment: Sure, I've modified the question. Apologize for inconvinence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  The `rex` command uses a regex to extract the duration from each event.  The `where` command filters out those not over 5000ms.  Finally, `stats` counts the remaining events, leaving the number of events with values greater than 5000ms.

```
index=1234 application_instance_name=service-name "[FooBarService#write] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (*)"
| rex "\((?<ms>\d+)ms"
| where ms > 5000
| stats count
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected.

Comment: if there's a '.' or other special characters then you've to escape it.